# Auto select value from dropdown from <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tags

I have a block of code in a page where a user has to select the package from available packages.

```
<a href="#block"> VVIP <a>
<a href="#block"> VIP <a>
<a href="#block"> Median <a>
<a href="#block"> General <a>
```

Based on the user selection I want to select a drop-down value in the form. The form is available on the same page.

```
<select>
    <option selected="" value="Default">Select Package</option>
    <option value="1">Kids Pass</option>
    <option value="2">Single Adult Pass</option>
    <option value="3">Couple Pass</option>
    <option value="4">Single Day Pass</option>
</select>
```

please help me if any HTML or JavaScript solution.

Comment: If you can share any example, then it will make more sense of you requirement.

Comment: how far you tried to solve. add any js or jquery code

Comment: Chirag, please explain what result you want, elaborate your question in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need,you were looking for events using JS

```js
function selectauto(nameofpackage)
{    
    var element = document.getElementById('packages');
    element.value = nameofpackage;
}
```

```html
<a href="#block" onclick="selectauto(1)"> VVIP <a><br>
<a href="#block" onclick="selectauto(2)"> VIP <a><br>
<a href="#block" onclick="selectauto(3)"> Median <a><br>
<a href="#block" onclick="selectauto(4)"> General <a><br>
<select id="packages">
    <option selected="" value="Default">Select Package</option>
    <option value="1">Kids Pass</option>
    <option value="2">Single Adult Pass</option>
    <option value="3">Couple Pass</option>
    <option value="4">Single Day Pass</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Prags, what can if <a> tag and DropDown on a different page?

Comment: you can pass that that a tag variable in url and get the variable in that page @ChiragGojaria

Comment: Can you give me a demo for this one? I really need that and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing the options.selectedIndex Dom attribute with javascript

```js
function selectOption(index){ 
      document.getElementById("select_stuff").options.selectedIndex = index;
    }
```

```html
 <!--This will selectKids pass-->
    <a href="#block" onclick="selectOption(1);"> VVIP <a> 
    <!--This will Single Adult pass pass-->
    <a href="#block" onclick="selectOption(2);"> VIP <a>
    <!-- This will select Default -->
    <a href="#block" onclick="selectOption(0);"> Median <a>
    <!-- This will select Single Day pass -->
    <a href="#block" onclick="selectOption(4);"> General <a>
    
    <select id="select_stuff">
        <option selected="" value="Default">Select Package</option>
        <option value="1">Kids Pass</option>
        <option value="2">Single Adult Pass</option>
        <option value="3">Couple Pass</option>
        <option value="4">Single Day Pass</option>
    </select>
```